# Remote: GitLab: API is not accessible when trying to push commit

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a new commit that I am trying to push to my repo and I keep getting this error. I did some searching and found that `git push -u origin branch_name` might fix it but it didn’t. I also tried to disable branch protection and I still get this error. I am using the public gitlab service so this is not a privately controlled repo. Gitlab did a couple updates recently and I have been having issues since then. I have asked this same question on their forums but have yet to get any response from them. It is a large commit, about 1.5G before any compression but my repo can hold up to 10G so this shouldn't be the issue. Unless git has issues with one large commit like this.

```
$ git push -u origin develop
Counting objects: 32892, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (32892/32892), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32892/32892), 2.83 GiB | 391.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 32892 (delta 17971), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (17971/17971), completed with 20 local objects.
remote: GitLab: API is not accessible
To git@gitlab.com:huntergaming/mine-seeker.git
! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to ‘git@gitlab.com:huntergaming/mine-seeker.git’
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569555/how-to-resolve-gitlab-api-is-not-accessible-when-pushing-to-a-new-repository

Comment: Make a pull of the repository in another directory and make a push of something simple (like .gitignore edition), and verify if the push go thru successfully. It just will tell you if there is anything wrong with your code or the gitlab services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Gitlab. You can tell because of two things:

1. the messages are from the remote source (lines beginning with `remote:`)
2. the operation fails with `pre-receive hook declined`, which is a server-side hook.

The answers to this question ([How to resolve "GitLab: API is not accessible" when pushing to a new repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569555/how-to-resolve-gitlab-api-is-not-accessible-when-pushing-to-a-new-repository)) suggest that it could be the server running out of memory, which could be the case if you're pushing 1.5G at once.

I'd suggest contacting Gitlab support.