# GitLab: API is not accessible after pushing to gitlab

Tags: gitlab

After working on a branch, I have committed and pushed all changes to my GitLab repository, facing this error:

> GitLab: API is not accessible
>
> ! [remote rejected] feature/policy-template -> feature/policy-template
> (pre-receive hook declined)

Gitlab servers are live.

I have no commit in GitLab and there are no changes to commit on my local project, so I do not know how to proceed to push the changes I have been working on to Gitlab.

Comment: This is a similar issue like [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/49647)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "GitLab: API is not accessible" when pushing to a new repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569555/how-to-resolve-gitlab-api-is-not-accessible-when-pushing-to-a-new-repository)

Comment: @champion-runner Not really, I already checked Gitlab servers and all are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting the service.

`sudo gitlab-ctl restart`

`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Set the correct URL for the GitLab API in GitLab's configuration files.